# Connectionstring for EF with SQl Server Express

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I am trying to connect to a new Database which I want to use with EF.
Unfortunately, I am unable to build a proper connectionstring.
I am new to databases, so please be gentle. If anyone could point me to a link which explains ConnectionStrings I would be grateful.

My App.config looks like this:
*EDIT*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=C:\TestControlling\Controlling.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" ></add>
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Well how does your current connection string not work? Does it throw an error on connecting to the database? If so, what error? Have you looked at examples of connection strings on Google?

Comment: @Arran EF simply throws an exception, the innermost exception simply says that the file could not be found. I have updated my conncetionstrings, see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what mode you're using entity framework in. If you're using code first I believe you just need a standard SqlClient connection string. The format is something like this:

```
Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=True
```

This article should help you along@ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

If you're using database first with entity framework, then you'll need a entity connection string that looks something like this:

```
metadata=res://*/modelName.csdl|res://*/modelName.ssdl|res://*/modelName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=serverName;initial catalog=databaseName;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'
```

This link should help with that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/cc716756.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the links, I really liked them. The real PRoblem was the "add name" Part, which contained an invalid name. The names was generated by visual studio, so I am a little bit surprised.